# How can I modify an operator in order to call it twice in a row in the same statement, in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I hope my question is clear. I'm using Qt and I want to create my own logger of sorts in order to write messages to a text file. I've started with this:

```
class QLogger
{
public:
    QLogger(QString filename);

    void operator<<(const QString &s){
        logFile->open(QFile::Append);
        QTextStream writer(logFile);
        writer << s;
        logFile->close();
    }

    void operator<<(const quint64 &ui){
        logFile->open(QFile::Append);
        QTextStream writer(logFile);
        writer << ui;
        logFile->close();
    }

    void operator<<(const qint32 &ii){
        logFile->open(QFile::Append);
        QTextStream writer(logFile);
        writer << ii;
        logFile->close();
    }

private:
    QFile *logFile;

};
```

So if I do this:

```
QLogger logger("log.log");
logger << "Hola en";
logger << 23;
```

I works as expected. However if I try to do this:

```
logger << "Hola en" << 23;
```

Then I get the following compilation error:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'void' and 'int' to binary 'operator<<'
```

How can I define the operator in order to make the line work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360232/how-do-i-use-a-chain-of-operator-overloads-without-modifying-the-operands   please check this as a reference

Comment: Your various `operator<<` overloads need to return a `QLogger&` (i.e. `return(*this)`).

Answer (score 8):

```
logger << "Hola en" << 23;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(logger << "Hola en") << 23;
```

for the second call, the left-hand-side is the value yielded by expression `logger << "Hola en"` and the right-hand-side is `23`.

What you need here is to have `operator<<` return a reference to QLogger.

---

Unrelated:

Template programming can help you a lot in this case:

```
template <class T>
QLogger &operator<<(const T &value){
    logFile->open(QFile::Append);
    QTextStream writer(logFile);
    writer << value;
    logFile->close();
    return *this;
}
```